# HTA window_onUnload() not executing if script running

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

I have an HTA that takes some user input and runs a farely long vbscript.  I've noticed that if the user closes the HTA window while a script is running, the window_onUnload sub never executes.  What I'm trying to actually accomplish here is to Kill the process that's executing if the window is closed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Put the vbscript in the HTA.

Comment: The vbscript is in the HTA.  It's just running a loop to sendkeys to different putty sessions.  Everything works great, but I need to be able to end it if the window is closed.

Comment: If the HTA is ended the VBScript will not continue if the script is inside the HTA and not run as a separate process (i.e `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(...)` would be classed as a separate process).